# How to get node Bundle in hook_form_alter on field config form?

Tags: 8, entities

Can you wonderful people help me out please? I am altering the field config form `(content types > plan > manage fields > edit field)` and cannot seem to get the proper bundle out. Every time I call the [`bundle()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Abundle/8.2.x) function it returns the string `"field_config"`. However the bundle is supposed to be `"plan"`. Perhaps it's different because I am on the field config form, and not a node form?

Below is my code, the things I've tried and the field object showing the proper bundle. Does anyone know of another solution for me to get `"plan"` out?

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ThirdPartySettingsInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function rent_plan_custom_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
// print $form_id;

  switch ($form_id) {

    case 'field_config_edit_form':

        print $form['#title'];

        $field = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
        $field_name = $field->getName();  //returns correct field_plan_purpose

        //first try
        print $field->bundle(); //<---THIS RETURNS "field_config"

        //second try
        $bundle = FALSE;
        if ($form_object = $form_state->getFormObject()) {
            if ($form_object instanceof Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm) {
                $bundle = $form_object->getEntity()->bundle();
            } elseif ($form_object instanceof Drupal\field_ui\Form\FieldConfigEditForm) {
                $bundle = $form_object->getEntity()->bundle(); 
            }
            print $bundle; //<---THIS RETURNS "field_config"
        }

        //Field Object Results Below
        print '<pre>';
        print_r($field);
        print '</pre>';


    break;
  }
}
```

**Results from print_r($field)**

```
Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig Object
(
    [deleted:protected] => 
    [fieldStorage:protected] => Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig Object
        (
            [id:protected] => node.field_plan_purpose
            [field_name:protected] => field_plan_purpose
            [entity_type:protected] => node
            [type:protected] => text_long
            [module:protected] => text
            [settings:protected] => Array

            ... lots of more stuff
        )

    [id:protected] => node.plan.field_plan_purpose
    [field_name:protected] => field_plan_purpose
    [field_type:protected] => text_long
    [entity_type:protected] => node
    [bundle:protected] => plan
    [label:protected] => Purpose
    [description:protected] => 
    [settings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    ...lots more stuff
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`FieldDefinitionInterface::getTargetBundle`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldDefinitionInterface.php/interface/FieldDefinitionInterface/8.2.x)

> Gets the bundle the field is attached to.
>
> This method should not be confused with EntityInterface::bundle() (configurable fields are config entities, and thus implement both interfaces):
>
> - FieldDefinitionInterface::getTargetBundle() answers "as a field, which bundle are you attached to?".
> - EntityInterface::bundle() answers "as a (config) entity, what is your own bundle?" (not relevant in our case, the config entity types used to store the definitions of configurable fields do not have bundles).

e.g.

```
$target_bundle = $field->getTargetBundle();
```

Comment: Thank you! This was perfect for my needs and I see now how these methods are defined in FieldConfigBase

Answer (score 3):

[`FieldConfigBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldConfigBase.php/class/FieldConfigBase/8.2.x) has a method on it(*) called  [`getTargetBundle()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldConfigBase.php/function/FieldConfigBase%3A%3AgetTargetBundle/8.2.x). That will retrieve the field name.  To be safe, you should also probably use [`getTargetEntityTypeId()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldConfigBase.php/function/FieldConfigBase%3A%3AgetTargetEntityTypeId/8.2.x) to make sure you are dealing with a node:

```
$entity_type = $field->getTargetEntityTypeId();
$bundle = $field->getTargetBundle();
if ($entity_type === 'node' && $bundle === 'plan') {
  do_something_awesome();
}
```

Using a class-aware editor, like PHPStorm, will make things like this a lot easier because you add type-hints, and then it will autocomplete for you.  In most OO code and some procedural code, a good IDE will automagiclly figure out your types, so you don't need to add the hinting.

(*) You should really be looking at the interface(s) that these define.  The one of interest in this case is [`FieldDefinitionInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldDefinitionInterface.php/interface/FieldDefinitionInterface/8.2.x).